# Set INTERVAL as variable in mysql ADDDATE

Tags: mysql

I have this line in mysql:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM table
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), ADDDATE(DATE_OF_REG, INTERVAL 1 HOUR))) / 3600 >= 24
```

I also have a TIMEZONE column which stores the time difference from the server as a number.
How can I add this number somehow in the ADDDATE function?
E.g. ADDDATE(DATE_OF_REG, INTERVAL, TIMEZONE) or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MySQL available today, but according to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) the interval number can be an expression. See if this works:

```
ADDDATE(DATE_OF_REG, INTERVAL myTimeStamp HOUR)
```

If that doesn't work try this, which is more or less how it has to be done in Oracle:

```
ADDDATE(DATE_OF_REG, myTimeStamp * INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @interval_count = YourTimezoneColumn;
SELECT <columns>
FROM table
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), DATEDIFF(DATE_OF_REG, INTERVAL @interval_count HOUR)) / 3600 >= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the TIMESTAMPADD function.

Instead of this: `ADDDATE(DATE_OF_REG, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Write this: `TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, TIMEZONE, DATE_OF_REG)`